# Why force people to compile/build JAR files instead of just hosting the JAR file itself?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I'm a data scientist by training so I'm not fully aware of the rationale/justification for certain approaches to things. For example, several packages I need often require I download/install `maven`, `cmake`, etc. and then compile/build source code into JAR files. Given the need for the JAR file version of a package is fairly common, why not host the JAR file(s) themselves? For example, XGBoost? https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost

Comment: You should be able to have maven download the XGBoost jar from mvnrepository.com. Not sure what makes you think you need to build it from source.

Comment: @NathanHughes oftentimes packages will instruct the user to compile a JAR using Maven. What is the command to have Maven download the XGBoost jar from mvnrepository.com? Also, I searched the for jar on that website and did not find it.

Comment: Examples of configuring a repository are here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm not sure what that means. "To make Java or Scala library available to a Spark application, you can either bundle that dependency into the “uberjar” file containing your application code using a dependency management tool like sbt or mvn (which is Spark’s recommended method for pacakaging an application) or you can place a jar on the Spark server nodes and make sure that jar is on the classpath." https://jeff.klukas.net/writing/2018-07-26-lib.jar-java-library-python-package-both/

Comment: I'm working with Spark applications and need access to Java and/or Scala libraries, hence needing `jar` files.